# How do I check if my C# — MySQL connection was successful or, if it was not, return why?

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, authentication, connection

I am struggling a bit with this piece of C# code. Basically, what I'm trying to do is some kind of mechanism to check if, in first place, the user and password combination for my SQL server was correct, and then, check if the database exists.

The connection string would be like this:

```
connectionString = 
   "database=test;server=localhost;uid=" + usr.Text + ";pwd=" + pwd.Text;
```

The solution I'm trying to reach is one that can check the exception thrown and tell if it's about a wrong password, a wrong user, not found database, etcetera. I've seen the use of DbConnectionStringBuilder in some places but I'm not sure of how I should use it.

Comment: What happened to "connecting to the DB and catching whatever exception"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   string connectionString = "database=test;server=localhost;uid=" + usr.Text + ";pwd=" + pwd.Text;
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
     try
     {
       conn.Open();
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
       switch (ex.Number) 
       { 
         case 4060: // Invalid Database 
          ....
          break;
         case 18456: // Login Failed 
          ....
          break;
         default:
          ....
          break;
       } 
     }
   }
```

The full list of Sql Server exception numbers can be found by running

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that I can catch most of the exceptions that'll crash my program with this code. This is what I was looking for after all: some way to identify what kind of exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

[`DbConnection.Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.open.aspx) will fail with invalid credentials.

Comment: I believe it will also fail if the database (as specified in the connection string) does not exist.  So it comes down to parsing the exception to determine what the specific failure is.

Comment: @Coding there is usually some identifier for the type of failure; `SqlException.Number` in case of `SqlConnection`.