# Check MySql DB Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I wanted to create a mysql connection checker for my program and as always i used my usual advisor [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and i landed on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665953/how-do-i-check-if-my-c-sharp-mysql-connection-was-successful-or-if-it-was-not) and the answer was not exactly right.

**The Question is:**
How to check for a valid mysql connection at c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my own version to check mysql connection.

```
public static bool checkDB_Conn()
{
    var conn_info = "Server=address;Port=3306;Database=dbhere;Uid=admin;Pwd=123";
    bool isConn = false;
    MySqlConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_info);
        conn.Open();
        isConn = true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException a_ex)
    {
        /*
        Console.WriteLine("Check the Connection String.");
        Console.WriteLine(a_ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(a_ex.ToString());
        */
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        /*string sqlErrorMessage = "Message: " + ex.Message + "\n" +
        "Source: " + ex.Source + "\n" +
        "Number: " + ex.Number;
        Console.WriteLine(sqlErrorMessage);
        */
        isConn = false;
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            //http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html
            case 1042: // Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (Check Server,Port)
                break;
            case 0: // Access denied (Check DB name,username,password)
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return isConn;
}
```

Comment: You should use `using` instead of `finally`.

Comment: Yes i didnt know that "using" was closing the connection. Thanks

Comment: compying this code to my project error says : The name 'ConnectionState' does not exist in the current context.
both 
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
are present...

Comment: `System.Data.ConnectionState.Open` is the full path